# Parameters in bracket after a javascript function

Tags: javascript

I found a solution for google maps marker on stack-overflow. 
Here is the link. [Google Maps API Multiple Markers with Infowindows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106671/google-maps-api-multiple-markers-with-infowindows)

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', (function(marker,content,infowindow){ 
return function() {
    infowindow.setContent(content);
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
};
})(marker,content,infowindow));
```

My question is: What is the purpose of (marker,content,infowindow) being placed behind the javascript function? And what is it called? 
Thank you very much in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a IIFE  (Immediately Invoked Function Expression), the second parenthesis invokes the function and allows you to pass arguments to the function

```
(function () {
    //statements
})();
```

Check docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. Appreciate it much

Answer (score 1):

That is a self invoking function - that means it is immediately called with these parameters, just after declaration

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering my question.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the answer by Damian for the official name.

However, this is simply executing the function created by executing the first function.

If we breakup the code into multiple lines, it may make more sense:

```
const makeAFuction = function(marker,content,infowindow){ 
  return function() {
    infowindow.setContent(content);
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  };
}
const listener = makeAFunction(marker,content,infowindow);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', listener);
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining in details. Helpful to a beginner like me =)